# Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:1234/Ball” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”) error using modules

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling find the reason my scripts won't load to the browser.  I'm running a live server for this but I continue to get this error.  It goes away when in html I have: 'type="modules/javascript"' but he script isn't loaded, again. I am able to successfully get other script to run that are in the same format, so I'm sure it's something silly I'm overlooking but I cannot seem to find good information without falling into a rabit hole.

my html:
1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  2 <html lang="en">
  3 <head>
  4     <meta charset="UTF-8">
  5     <title>Bouncing Balls (Object Oriented Programming)</title>
  6     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  7     <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  8 </head>
  9 <body>
 10     <a href="bouncingBalls.html">Previous Page</a>
 11 
 12     <div class="canvas-container">
 13         <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1200" height="900"></canvas>
 14     </div>
 15 
 16 </body>
 17 </html>

// index.js file:
1 import Scene from './Scene.js';
    2 
>>  3 const animation = new Scene();

// Scene.js file:
import Ball from './Ball';

// Default values:
const defaultConfig = {
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        gravity: 0.25,
        friction: 0.98
}

// Classes are functions that create Objects:
export class Scene {
        // Constructor function is equivalent to init()
        constructor (canvasId = 'gameCanvas', config) {
                this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
                this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

                // Settings; merge default config and any passed in config by *spreading* them:
                this.conifg = {
                        ...defaultConfig,
                        ...config
                }

                this.canvas.width = this.config.width;
                this.canvas.height = this.config.height;

                this.createBalls();
                // Use arrow function so we can use 'this' property
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => this.update());
        }

        createBalls() {
                // Scene config:
                const { config } = this;
                // Random colors:
                const colors = ['purple', 'red', 'blue', 'brown'];
                // Array of ball obejcts:
                const balls = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        balls.push(new Ball(
                                // Random X and Y positions:
                                Math.random() * config.width, Math.random() * config.height,
                                // scen conifg:
                                {
                                        // default width, height, friciton:
                                        ...config,
                                        // random + or - gravity:
                                        gravity: config.gravity * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) || -1)
                                },
                                // ball properties:
                                {
                                        //extra bouncy:
                                        bounce: 0.90,
                                        radius: Math.random() * 20 + 10,
                                        color: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
                                }
                        ));
                }

                this.balls = balls;
        }

        update() {
                // *Destructure* scene's variables:
                const { ctx, config, balls } = this;

                // Queue the next update:
                window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.update());

                // clear canvas:
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, config.width, config.height);

                // update my balls!
                balls.forEach(ball => ball.update());
                // Draw objects:
                balls.forEach(ball => ball.draw(ctx));
        }
}

export default Scene;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```js
import Ball from './Ball';
```

To this:

```js
import Ball from './Ball.js'; // added .js to end of Ball
```

Your script is trying to read a html file named 'Ball' instead of a JavaScript file